# Custom html attribute in dom-repeat template in Polymer 0.9

Tags: templates, attributes, polymer

I'm trying to bind a field inside a dom-repeat template in polymer 0.9 to an custom attribute of a div tag. In other words, just some random attribute I made up (which seems to work fine in other circumstances), but the attribute never ends up getting added to the div (if I view in Inspect Element, my attribute isn't there).

example:

```
<div vendor-id="{{item.vendorId}}">
```

If I inspect the div, the 'vendor-id' attribute isn't there. If I bind the same thing to the 'id' attribute of the div, it binds perfectly fine. I can't use id though in my scenario because I have multiple of these divs within the same row. I'm storing the primary key for edit / delete functionality for a crud interface. Anyways, I'm sure I can work around this, but really want to ensure I understand why this custom attribute isnt getting added to the DOM. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try using data-* attributes instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.

You can use the `$=` assignment.

`<div any$="{{binding}}"></div>`

It is stated in the [Polymer docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding).

I hope that answers your question.